# Is it possible to use Custom UI with ResearchKit Framework?

Tags: ios8, xib, ios8.1, ios8.3, ios-frameworks

I am developing a simple app using ResearchKit framework and I have created my own User Interface. As ResearchKit provides pre-built user interface, is there any way that I can use my UI instead of the one provided by ResearchKit. If so, how to integrate?? I am using xibs.

Answer (score 0):

ResearchKit is an open source project and it's code is available at https://github.com/researchkit/researchkit.
So nothing stop you from forking the project and fully customizing any aspect.

It seem like most of the UI is coded directly in code (not XIB) so you will have to get your hands dirty.